# Initialize Component Function not working and btnstop not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, arduino

I am currently trying to create a voice recognition feature to do with Arduino and I have utilized this code(it is not mine). The btnstop.Enabled and btnstart.Enabled are not working and the IntializeComponent() is saying that "doesn't exist in this context".

With the System.IO.Ports Assembly, there is supposed to be something called SerialPort(), which I had verified with the library guide online. I am getting this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrtSH.png)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports; // This library is for connecting c# and Arduino to transmit and receive data through ports
//Below are libraries for voice recognition
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace CsharpCode
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //Creating objects
        SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();
        SpeechRecognitionEngine re = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer(); // When you want program to talk back to you 
        Choices commands = new Choices(); // This is an important class as name suggest we will store our commands in this object


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Details of Arduino board
            myPort.PortName = "COM5"; // My Port name in Arduino IDE selected COM5 you need to change Port name if it is different  just check in arduinoIDE
            myPort.BaudRate = 9600;  // This Rate is Same as arduino Serial.begin(9600) bits per second
            processing();

        }

        // Defined Function processing where main instruction will be executed ! 
        void processing()
        {
            //First of all storing commands
            commands.Add(new string[] { "Blue On", "Red On", "Green On", "Blue Off", "Red Off", "Green Off", "Exit", "All On", "All Off", "Arduino Say Good Bye to makers" });

            //Now we will create object of Grammer in which we will pass commands as parameter
            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(commands));

            // For more information about below funtions refer to site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.recognition?view=netframework-4.7.2
            re.RequestRecognizerUpdate(); // Pause Speech Recognition Engine before loading commands
            re.LoadGrammarAsync(gr);
            re.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();// As Name suggest input device builtin microphone or you can also connect earphone etc...
            re.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(re_SpeechRecognized);


        }

        void re_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {
                ////For Led State ON 
                // For blue led
                case "Blue On":
                    sendDataToArduino('B');
                    break;

                // For red led
                case "Red On":
                    sendDataToArduino('R');
                    break;

                // For green led
                case "Green On":
                    sendDataToArduino('G');
                    break;

                //For Led State OFF 
                // For blue led
                case "Blue Off":
                    sendDataToArduino('Z');
                    break;

                // For red led
                case "Red Off":
                    sendDataToArduino('X');
                    break;

                // For green led
                case "Green Off":
                    sendDataToArduino('C');
                    break;

                //For turning ON all leds at once :)
                case "All On":
                    sendDataToArduino('V');
                    break;

                //For turning OFF all leds at once :)
                case "All Off":
                    sendDataToArduino('M');
                    break;
                //Program will talk back 
                case "Arduino Say Good Bye to makers":
                    ss.SpeakAsync("Good Bye Makers"); // speech synthesis object is used for this purpose
                    break;

                // To Exit Program using Voice :)
                case "Exit":
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
            }
            txtCommands.Text += e.Result.Text.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;// Whenever we command arduino text will append and shown in textbox
        }

        void sendDataToArduino(char character)
        {
            myPort.Open();
            myPort.Write(character.ToString());
            myPort.Close();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            re.RecognizeAsyncStop();
            //btnStart.Enabled = true;
            btnStop.Enabled = false;
            btnStart.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            re.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            btnStop.Enabled = true;
            btnStart.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Voice Recognition Started !", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"?  are you getting an error when attempting to build/compile? are you getting a runtime exception? update your question to include what these errors are that you are referring to.

Comment: Are you sure you subscribed to the button click events? Try debugging the program. If breakpoint is not hitting IntializeComponent then the issue could be in "creating objects" section.